# devbridge jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, select, combobox, dropdown, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been looking for an autocomplete plugin & devbridge's seems to be really usable, and well documented.
However, I do have a question unanswered by the documentation, it seems , nor by any of the answers / questions on SO:
I would like to use remotely collected data  (using ajax/JSON...) and output the pair id / value so that the value is searched, and displayed but the id is used in the 'value' field of the input , much in the way a select / option would do,as the below every basic example below illustrates:

```
<select name="pets" id="pet_id">
    <option value="" disabled >--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="1">Dog</option>
    <option value="5">Cat</option>
    <option value="2">Hamster</option>
    <option value="6">Parrot</option>
    <option value="8">Spider</option>
    <option value="10">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

*PS: note that I voluntarily typed in non-sequential values to avoid confusing the issue ..*

I have seen the use of a "link" to another field to display either the ID (*value*)  or the selected result of the search, in other plugins, but I would like to go for a simpler , more user friendly approach mimicking / using the select / option HTML combobox input
Could anyone knowledgeable on this plugin set me on the way ?
Many thanks!
JMB

Comment: You can use remotely created content. Please provide more details about your code and what you are trying to accomplish. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi!  
What I'm trying to accomplish is obvious from my question : mimicking the pure HTML''s "SELECT " behavior (eg posting an id, and showing an item) using the autocomplete feature to search & complete the item's '"name".   The remote content is not the issue ...  
Just rephrasing here...no need for a "reproductible" example !  
 I wonder why bother answering in that manner ... That's neither helpful, nor shows real interest for the question /or answer, for that matter. !